# Is there way to split Data In One Field of Table into Two Fields(Columns) for Printing in MySQL

Tags: mysql

To make things more clear, let us first create a sample table

```
CREATE TABLE table_test(
ID INT,
Item VARCHAR(100),
Amount DOUBLE,
Item_Mode VARCHAR(10)
);
```

Now we can enter some sample data

```
INSERT  INTO `table_test`(`ID`,`Item`,`Amount`,`Item_Mode`) VALUES
(1,'Allowances',100.00,'a'),
(2,'HRA',200.00,'a'),
(3,'DA',100.00,'a'),
(4,'FBP',100.00,'a'),
(5,'Income Tax',50.00,'d'),
(6,'Insurance ',10.00,'d'),
(7,'Provident Fund',20.00,'d');
```

We have two types of data here. Mode a and Mode d.

| ID | Item | Amount | Item_Mode |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Allowance | 100.00 | a |
| 2 | HRA | 200.00 | a |
| 3 | DA | 100.00 | a |
| 4 | FBP | 100.00 | a |
| 5 | Income Tax | 50.00 | d |
| 6 | Insurance | 10.00 | d |
| 7 | Provident Fund | 20.00 | d |

I want to show it all the 'a' data in one column and all the 'd' data in next column. How can I achieve this.

I tried

```
SELECT A.Item AS EARN,B.Item AS DEDUCT
FROM Table A INNER JOIN TABLE B
ON A.ID = B.ID  WHERE MOD(A.ID,2)=1 AND A.Mode = 'a' OR B.Mode = 'd'
```

The above query pumped out a wrong answer.

The expected dataset must display data like below

| IDA | ItemA | AmountA | Item_ModeA | IDB | ItemB | AmountB | Item_ModeB |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Allowance | 100.00 | a | 5 | Income Tax | 50.00 | d |
| 2 | HRA | 200.00 | a | 6 | Insurance | 10.00 | d |
| 3 | DA | 100.00 | a | 7 | Provident Fund | 20.00 | d |
| 4 | FBP | 100.00 | a |  |  |  |  |

Answer (score 0):

You can use the next `SELECT` statement:

```
WITH group_a AS (
  SELECT id idA, item ItemA, amount AmountA, Item_Mode Item_ModeA,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) AS row_num_A
  FROM Table
  WHERE Item_Mode = 'a'
), group_b AS (
  SELECT id idB, item ItemB, amount AmountB, Item_Mode Item_ModeB,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) AS row_num_B
  FROM Table
  WHERE Item_Mode = 'd'
)
SELECT a.idA, a.itemA, a.AmountA, a.Item_ModeA, 
       a.idB, a.itemB, a.AmountB, a.Item_ModeB 
FROM group_a AS a
    LEFT JOIN group_b AS b ON a.row_num_A = b.row_num_B
ORDER BY a.row_num_A;
```

Note: if count of rows in the `group_b` is bigger, then you can lose the data due to `LEFT JOIN`.

**Update**

If counts of these two parts are different time-to-time, then you can change the last two lines:

```
    FULL OUTER JOIN group_b AS b ON a.row_num_A = b.row_num_B
ORDER BY COALESCE(a.row_num_A, b.row_num_B);
```

**Update**
For the MySQL 5.5

```
SELECT a.id idA, a.item ItemA, a.amount AmountA, a.Item_Mode Item_ModeA,
       b.id idB, b.item ItemB, b.amount AmountB, b.Item_Mode Item_ModeB
FROM (
      SELECT id, item, amount, Item_Mode,
           (SELECT COUNT() FROM Table t2 WHERE t2.Item_Mode = 'a' AND t2.id <= t1.id) AS row_num_A
      FROM Table t1
      WHERE Item_Mode = 'a'
) AS a
LEFT JOIN (
      SELECT id, item, amount, Item_Mode,
           (SELECT COUNT() FROM Table t2 WHERE t2.Item_Mode = 'd' AND t2.id <= t1.id) AS row_num_B
      FROM Table t1
      WHERE Item_Mode = 'd'
) AS b ON a.row_num_A = b.row_num_B

UNION

SELECT a.id idA, a.item ItemA, a.amount AmountA, a.Item_Mode Item_ModeA,
       b.id idB, b.item ItemB, b.amount AmountB, b.Item_Mode Item_ModeB
FROM (
      SELECT id, item, amount, Item_Mode,
           (SELECT COUNT() FROM Table t2 WHERE t2.Item_Mode = 'a' AND t2.id <= t1.id) AS row_num_A
      FROM Table t1
      WHERE Item_Mode = 'a'
) AS a
RIGHT JOIN (
      SELECT id, item, amount, Item_Mode,
           (SELECT COUNT() FROM Table t2 WHERE t2.Item_Mode = 'd' AND t2.id <= t1.id) AS row_num_B
      FROM Table t1
      WHERE Item_Mode = 'd'
) AS b ON a.row_num_A = b.row_num_B
WHERE a.id IS NULL
ORDER BY COALESCE(a.row_num_A, b.row_num_B);
```

Here:

- LEFT JOIN and RIGHT JOIN instead of FULL OUTER JOIN
- UNION to combine the results of the left and right joins
- subqueries to compute the row numbers instead of the OVER() clause

Comment: Dear Friend @Aksen P MySQL version is 5.5. I cannot use the above query. If you have any other query to replace the above please post it. Thank you so much for your effort.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the number of items `a` always 4 and higher than number of items `d`, then you can do it using `self left join` with a condition `(a.ID mod 4) = (b.ID mod 4)`

If we take this query :

```
select *, ID mod 4
from table_test
```

it will Result :

```
ID  Item          Amount    Item_Mode   ID mod 4
1   Allowances    100       a           1
2   HRA           200       a           2
3   DA            100       a           3
4   FBP           100       a           0
5   Income Tax    50        d           1
6   Insurance     10        d           2
7   Provident Fund20        d           3
```

As you can see the first record with item `a` can be matched with first item `d` because both having `ID mod 4 = 1`

So the query can be :

```
select a.ID as idA, a.Item as itemA, a.Amount as amountA, a.Item_Mode as item_modeA,
  b.ID as idB,  b.Item as itemB, b.Amount as amoutB,    b.Item_Mode as item_modeB
from table_test a
left join table_test b 
      on (a.ID mod 4) = (b.ID mod 4) 
      and a.Item_Mode <> b.Item_Mode
where a.Item_Mode = 'a'
```

Result :

| idA | itemA | amountA | item_modeA | idB | itemB | amoutB | item_modeB |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Allowances | 100 | a | 5 | Income Tax | 50 | d |
| 2 | HRA | 200 | a | 6 | Insurance | 10 | d |
| 3 | DA | 100 | a | 7 | Provident | Fund | 20 |
| 4 | FBP | 100 | a | null | null | null | null |

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/2CrtjrPX)

If the number of rows of items a and d can be any number then :

```
with cte as (
  select *, count(ID) over (partition by Item_Mode) as count_items,
            row_number() over (partition by Item_Mode) as rn,
            row_number() over() - row_number() over (partition by Item_Mode) as grp
  from table_test
),
cte2 as (
  select *, case when max(count_items) over() = count_items then 1 else 0 end as havingMoreRows
  from cte c
),
item_mode_with_more_rows as (
  select *
  from cte2
  where havingMoreRows = 1
),
item_mode_with_less_rows as (
  select *
  from cte2
  where havingMoreRows = 0
)
select a.ID as idA, a.Item as itemA, a.Amount as amountA, a.Item_Mode as item_modeA,
  b.ID as idB,  b.Item as itemB, b.Amount as amoutB, b.Item_Mode as item_modeB
from item_mode_with_more_rows a
left join item_mode_with_less_rows b 
     on a.rn = b.rn 
     and a.Item_Mode <> b.Item_Mode
```

First `cte` used to group items by mode.

Second `cte` will find the item with the highest number of rows(in the simple data it is `a` with 4 items).

`item_mode_with_more_rows` to get set of records from the biggest mode.

`item_mode_with_less_rows` to get set of records from the smallest mode.

Then using a `left join` we get the expected output

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/OqQtazAW)

Comment: What if rows of `a` will be 10? 100? What will be your output? And the same for `b` table?

Comment: I made an update to make it more dynamic

Comment: Dear Friends, I forgot to tell you an Important point. MySQL Version is 5.5. So I cannot use cte. Sorry that I did not mention it. Next,  Number of Records with mode a may be >= mode d or mode a may be = mode d or mode a  may be <= mode d. Could you please help me with this. I tried all  query. Since I cannot use CTE I took @SelVazi code it works perfect with the above number and pattern of records. If we add one more record for mode  a and one more record for mode d. Then this will not work. Anyway Thank you so much for your effort. Please help me to achieve  this.